# Capture recurring regex patterns in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a pattern

```
ab 23 cde 25 ... and so on
```

Can I capture the above pattern like

```
array(
 [patterns] => array(
   [0] => array(
    [payer] => 'ab'
    [amt] => 23
   )
   [1] => array(
    [payer] => 'cde'
    [amt] => 25
   )
 )
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible; php is Turing complete! Or are you asking how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_match_all` for this as:

```
$str = 'ab 23 cde 25';
preg_match_all('/(\w+)\s+(\d+)/',$str,$matches);
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++) {
        $result[] = array('payer' => $matches[1][$i], 'amt' => $matches[2][$i]);
}
```

[**Working link**](http://www.ideone.com/rZfVy)

Comment: Thanks. preg_match_all would do. Anyway this recurring pattern is part of a non-recurring pattern, so I guess anyway I would have to first get this recurring pattern out of it then run preg_match_all on it.

Answer (score 0):

Form a regex to match each item in your array (`\w+\s+\d+`). Collect all of them (this should give you chunks like `ab 23`).

Then for each of these items, split on whitespace and cram into your larger array as [payer], [amt].

Comment: I think you meant `\w+\s+\d+`. `\w*\s*\d*` will *always* match because it can legally match zero characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:'|.)(\w+)(?:'|$)
```